# hide or show columns in grafana with a variable

Tags: mysql, grafana

so i am creating this table, however i am trying to hide / show columns based on a variable (user can select which columns she/he sees).

I came with the following code:

```
select 
Rank() over (Partition BY  score
ORDER BY Speler) ranking,
Speler, $column, Rank as '# pred', Naam as 'Team pred', position as '#', score from fact_score_sheet_act
where Speler in ($Names)
ORDER BY Speler, Competitie, RANK ASC
```

$column is a variable containing the column names
it only shows the name as value, instead of values from the database,

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know grafana, but in mysql (and sql in general) the column and table names can't be dynamic, you must pre-generate the sql statement containing all column and table names in a fixed manner. You really need to decide if this is an sql or a grafana question as the answer may be different

Answer (score 2):

Your variable is substituted with quoted comma-separated list. As a result MySql interprets it as a list of strings, and returns them as such.

[Documentation](https://%20https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#advanced-variable-format-options) on this matter says:

> [T]he default for the MySql data source is to join multiple values as comma-separated with quotes: 'server01','server02'. In some cases, you might want to have a comma-separated string without quotes: server01,server02. You can make that happen with advanced variable formatting options listed below.

Use `${column:csv}` in your query instead.